# RT3060 Wireless on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, ralink

My Wireless Connection is working fine on my newly installed Ubuntu 13.04. But Im trying to improve my wireless connection by installing the driver. The stock driver that is built into ubuntu has weak signal

Here are my wireless card details (done via "lspci -v")

```
 04:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
    Subsystem: Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 21
    Memory at fb100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

I had downloaded DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217.tgz from RALINK website (now mediatek) and did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
cd angepasster-DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
echo "blacklist rt2800pci" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt3562sta
```

However I run into errors that was not encountered in the past ubuntu versions (12.04 and 12.10)

from the command "make":

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/tools'
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_sha2.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_hmac.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘WscEncryptData’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1522:1: warning: the frame size of 1408 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘WscDecryptData’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1592:1: warning: the frame size of 1408 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘AES_GTK_KEY_WRAP’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:2265:1: warning: the frame size of 1608 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘AES_GTK_KEY_UNWRAP’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:2348:1: warning: the frame size of 1144 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/crypt_arc4.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/mlme.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c: In function ‘MlmeResetRalinkCounters’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:867:2: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:867:2: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c: In function ‘BssTableSetEntry’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:5657:39: warning: operation on ‘Tab->BssOverlapNr’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wep.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/action.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c: In function ‘NICInitAsicFromEEPROM’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c:1391:4: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_tkip.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_aes.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/dfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.c: In function ‘PeerMeasureReportAction’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.c:1966:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_timer.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rt_channel.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_profile.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/auth.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/auth_rsp.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/ags.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c: In function ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:596:1: warning: the frame size of 1288 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlMAC’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:5844:1: warning: the frame size of 1336 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlE2PROM’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:6043:1: warning: the frame size of 1344 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘duplicate_pkt’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:482:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:100,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:14,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:4,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/include/os/rt_linux.h:31,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/include/rtmp_os.h:32,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/include/rt_config.h:60,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:28:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:484:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:100,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:14,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:4,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/include/os/rt_linux.h:31,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/include/rtmp_os.h:32,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/include/rt_config.h:60,
                 from /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:28:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘ClonePacket’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:634:23: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘update_os_packet_info’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:656:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘wlan_802_11_to_802_3_packet’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:677:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘send_monitor_packets’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:950:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSNetDevDetach’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1699:38: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSNetDevAttach’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1736:38: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_main_dev.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_main_dev.c: In function ‘MainVirtualIF_close’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_main_dev.c:118:13: warning: unused variable ‘Cancelled’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_main_dev.c: In function ‘WriteDatThread’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_main_dev.c:1250:3: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c: In function ‘convert_reordering_packet_to_preAMSDU_or_802_3_packet’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c:1558:2: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c: In function ‘RTMPResetTxRxRingMemory’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:36:13: warning: unused variable ‘num’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c: In function ‘RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:119:16: warning: unused variable ‘IrqFlags’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:118:16: warning: unused variable ‘pPacket’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:117:15: warning: unused variable ‘pTxD’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:116:16: warning: unused variable ‘pTxRing’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:115:19: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:115:6: warning: unused variable ‘index’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c: In function ‘RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory’:
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:447:11: warning: unused variable ‘BufBaseVa’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:446:11: warning: unused variable ‘BufBasePaLow’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:445:11: warning: unused variable ‘BufBasePaHigh’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:432:15: warning: unused variable ‘pPacket’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:431:15: warning: unused variable ‘pDmaBuf’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:430:16: warning: unused variable ‘pTxRing’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:428:14: warning: unused variable ‘pRxD’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:427:14: warning: unused variable ‘pTxD’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:425:10: warning: unused variable ‘RingBaseVa’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:424:10: warning: unused variable ‘RingBasePaLow’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:423:10: warning: unused variable ‘RingBasePaHigh’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:489:4: warning: ‘index’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_pci.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/ee_prom.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/ee_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../common/rt_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../chips/rt30xx.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../chips/rt35xx.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_pci_rbus.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_rbus_pci_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.o
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:37:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:38:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_probe’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:60:46: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__devinitdata’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:101:17: error: ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:102:17: error: ‘rt2860_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:104:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:104:29: error: ‘rt2860_remove_one’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:297:24: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_probe’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:471:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:536:14: warning: ‘RTMPInitPCIeDevice’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:87:1: error: ‘__mod_pci_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/run/user/root/gvfs’: Is a directory
```

from the command "make install":

```
make -C /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux -f Makefile.6 install
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/Wireless’: File exists
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux'
rm -rf /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA
mkdir /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA
cp /home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/RT2860STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/.
install -d /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install -m 644 -c rt3562sta.ko /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 3.8.0-19-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/stefan/Desktop/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux'
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/run/user/root/gvfs’: Is a directory
```

and lastly from the "modprobe -v rt3562sta":

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt3562sta.ko 
ERROR: could not insert 'rt3562sta': Exec format error
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/run/user/root/gvfs’: Is a directory
```

Can someone enlighten me where went wrong?

Comment: Very simply, I suspect the driver you are trying to compile was written in 2010 for, probably, a 3.2-xx kernel version. Ubuntu 13.04 uses 3.8.0-xx. There are too many differences for it to compile cleanly. I suggest you try to get rt2800pci to work as intended.

Comment: Thanks.  Im new with this compiling thing. 

Thanks for the advice. I'll try that rt2800pci